# GNU readline library bracket matching

Tags: c, readline

I have been looking thru GNU manuals and googling about the readline library these days. I always wonders how to customize the behaviours of the real TUI such as auto-completion, key-bindings etc. But the main problem I'm concerning now is bracket matching, which I would be using in a lisp repl.

However, when I google about bracket matching in the GNU readline library, the answers always includes setting the `blink-matching-paren` option in the `.input.rc` init file. Is there a programmatic way to do it, like calling a function or passing in special parameters?

Also, I looked into lisp implementation source codes like `clisp`'s and `Hy`'s repl system, but I found out nothing about `readline` or command line editing etc. Can anyone help me?